# command to get the number cpu exists on vmware

Tags: powershell, vmware, esxi, powercli, esx

Is there any cli command to know the configuration details of VM like, number of existing cpus, number of network cards etc., in VM.

Answer (score 2):

### Linux

`cat /proc/cpuinfo` for processor info.
`cat /proc/meminfo` for memory info
`df -H` for partition info in human readable size format
`lspci` for pci device info (such as network card)
`ifconfig` or `ip addr sh` for enabled network interfaces (virtual and physical)

### Windows

`msinfo32 /report c:\sysinfo.txt` and `type c:\sysinfo.txt` should get you all you could want

Answer (score 2):

The vSphere PowerCLI can do this for you from powershell. From [here](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1513287):

```
Get-VM | `
  ForEach-Object {
    $Report = "" | Select-Object -property Name,NumCpu,MemoryMB,Host,IPAddress
    $Report.Name = $_.Name
    $Report.NumCpu = $_.NumCpu
    $Report.MemoryMB = $_.MemoryMB
    $Report.Host = $_.Host
    $Report.IPAddress = $_.Guest.IPAddress
  Write-Output $Report
  } | Export-Csv "C:\VM.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use 'foreach-object' powershell can manage it.

Get-VM | Select-Object -property Name,NumCpu,MemoryMB,Host,IPAddress | Export-Csv "C:\VM.csv"

Answer (score 0):

`lscpu` is also useful on Linux. More readable than `cat /proc/cpuinfo`